# Displaying date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used date picker and stored it into Mongo collection. I am trying to display it in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`. But I want weekday of the date (`i:e:` MON, TUE, etc), date and month (in words like JAN, FEB, etc).

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you...

```
   function isDate_DD_MMM_YYYY(inputString) {
   var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(?:(\d{1,2})|(jan)|(feb)|(mar)|(apr)|(may)|(jun)|(jul)|(aug)|(sep)|(oct)|(nov)|(dec))(\/|-)(\d{4})$/i;
   var dateParts = (inputString.value).match(rxDatePattern);
     if (dateParts != null)
       return true;
     else
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for date

```
  <?php echo "date:".date("D/M/yyyy",strtotime($yourdate)); ?>
```

Comment: i dont see a php tag on OP